# Error while importing pyVim.connect

Tags: python, pip, vmware, pyvmomi

I am attempting to run the following code which I received from samples [here](https://github.com/vmware/pyvmomi-community-samples/blob/master/samples/get_vm_names.py)

```
from __future__ import print_function
import atexit
from pyVim.connect import SmartConnectNoSSL, Disconnect
from pyVmomi import vim
from tools import cli
```

I am receiving the following error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No Module named 'pyVim.connect'
```

The packages in question are from [here](https://github.com/vmware/pyvmomi) and were installed using:

```
pip install pyvmomi
```

Is there something wrong with how I am installing these packages?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like the code was a bit old. Importing 'pyvim' instead of 'pyVim' worked,  though it seems to be named 'pyVim' on the github.

Answer (score 4):

It's possible that you need to reinstall `pvmomi` to force the re-install of additional files in the `pyVim/` package dir:

```
pip3 install --force pyvmomi
```

Answer (score 3):

I haven't figured out how or what causes this, but the issue seems to occur on case-insensitive macOS file systems.

Since it has different behavior than Linux and case-sensitive macOS, I use the following "hack" to make it compatible between systems:

```py
try:
    from pyVim.connect import SmartConnectNoSSL
except ImportError:
    from pyvim.connect import SmartConnectNoSSL
```

PS: You can use `diskutil info /` on macOS to figure out if your file system is case-sensitive or not ([Details in another StackExchange question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/71360/178442))